# How to replay keystrokes without modifiers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using pynput, I am trying to capture keys and it involves keys like shift-1, cmd-1(i am on macos) etc

The problem I am facing is if I were to press shift-1 on my keyboard, it's recorded as shift-! (modified), and when I press shift-2 its recorded as shift-@. Hence when I replay these key strokes, it doesn't work as intended.

Key strokes with cmd key is also not working as intended.

Please point me to the right direction as I need the keys to be replayed as exactly as recorded.

disclaimer: I got these codes from the web and trying to modify it.

```
from pynput import mouse, keyboard

def on_press(key):
    print(key)
    try:
        json_object = {
            'action':'pressed_key', 
            'key':key.char, 
            '_time': time.time()
        }
    except AttributeError:
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            print("Keyboard recording ended.")
            return False

        json_object = {
            'action':'pressed_key', 
            'key':str(key), 
            '_time': time.time()
        }
        
    recording.append(json_object)


def on_release(key):
    try:
        json_object = {
            'action':'released_key', 
            'key':key.char, 
            '_time': time.time()
        }
    except AttributeError:
        json_object = {
            'action':'released_key', 
            'key':str(key), 
            '_time': time.time()
        }

    recording.append(json_object)

    keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release)

    keyboard_listener.start()
    keyboard_listener.join()
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use a match&case to switch the '!' -> a 'shift + 1' etc. And I am not sure about the cmd key, I looked at the api doc and it will act different depending on mac/pc

Comment: There are two widely used standards for encoding extended keys. I have never used the Python `pynput` module. It either has a bug or is incompatible with how your terminal encodes extended keys. Note that historically, something like Shift-1 would send a literal `!` character. It is only relatively recently that applications could ask the "terminal" to send an extended key sequence indicating the Shift modifier was used with the `1` key. Sadly, there are two implementations for doing that encoding.

Comment: Reading the `pyinput` documentation is appears it does not handle input from a "terminal" over a serial connection. It appears to hook into the native UI standard such as X11 on Linux. So my previous comment is probably irrelevant. Your example code is also obviously incorrect since the last six lines are obviously not meant to be part of the `on_release` function. Which means there are probably other problems with your code you are asking us to help you with.